Is there a way to restore the soul points of someone who made a soul pact?
In The Book Of Madness(Revised) the game offers mechanics for selling one's soul piecemeal at a time. Each mage has a (Willpower+Arete)*10 soul points which is the amount of their soul they can trade away before they are fully enslaved by the demon they are bargaining with. Is there a way for these points to be restored whether it be through the removal of the investments(The demonic powers you get from them) or through usage of spirit sphere in order to cut out the malignant parts of the soul and then help the soul recover?

https://whitewolf.fandom.com/wiki/The_Book_of_Madness

Thank you. I'll edit the link into the question.

With WoD, it's often helpful to link to the book's entry: there are 3 books named umbra and between 2 and 3 players' guides per mainline. In that case: there is a 1st edition and a Revisied edition! Whcih one do you refer to?

It's unlikely
The only section in the revised Book of Madness that mentions the term Soul Points is that about how they get traded away (p. 89f, apart from one side mention on p. 85). If there were any additional rules in the book allowing you to gain Soul Points back they should mention the term.
Beyond that, there is also a whole section on how you will lose your avatar eventually, titled "Nothing's Free" (p. 94), so even if you were able to negotiate perfectly and get all your investments without losing any of your Soul Points, the demon lord will still get you in the end. It concludes by explaining the game design reasons for this:

If these guidelines seem harsh, consider this: At its heart, Mage is a game in which characters seek to change the world through the power of their beliefs — of their faith, their genius, their Will.
An Infernalist is a slave, and an Infernalist mage has thrown away any destiny he might have had to be nothing more than a puppet to an inhuman master. The very concept of Infernalism — spiritual slavery in exchange for material power — stands as a complete anathema to the very idea behind Mage

That is, it is intentional that being an Infernalist is a one-way trip to slavery. Allowing rules to game this to gather power without cost, or to escape the decision to trade away your soul is anathema to this.
